# BindingExpression path error

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

There are many similar questions and I've tried a number of answers from those questions but so far nothing helps. I do not understand what the error message means actually. The error message is;

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'CategoryModel' 
property not found on 'object' ''String' (HashCode=-57655201)'.
BindingExpression:Path=CategoryModel.CategoryList; DataItem='String'
(HashCode=-57655201); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is
'Text' (type 'String')
```

CategoryList contains a string list of categories which are full (checked from debug). My xaml is below,

```
<ListView x:Name="categoryListView" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="56" Height="156" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=CategoryModel.CategoryList}" 
              DisplayMemberPath="CategoryModel.CategoryList" 
              SelectedValue="{Binding Path=CategoryModel.SelectedCategory}"
              VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
</ListView>
```

The xaml design looks ok, application runs fine but nothing gets filled. The categoryList is supposed to be filled at initialization. It is filled actually but listView doesn't show anything.

EDIT:

The CategoryModel;

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace RecorderApp.Model
{
public class CategoryModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private String _selectedCategory;
    private String _recordTitle;
    private String _systemInfoLabel;


    private ObservableCollection<String> _categoryList;

    public ObservableCollection<String> CategoryList
    {
        get { return _categoryList; }

        set
        {
            if (_categoryList != value)
            {
                _categoryList = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("CategoryList");
            }
        }
    }

    public String SystemInfoLabel
    {
        get { return _systemInfoLabel; }

        set
        {
            if (_systemInfoLabel != value)
            {
                _systemInfoLabel = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SystemInfoLabel");
            }
        }
    }

    public String SelectedCategory
    {
        get { return _selectedCategory; }

        set
        {
            if (_selectedCategory != value)
            {
                _selectedCategory = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SelectedCategory");
            }
        }
    }

    public string RecordTitle
    {
        get { return _recordTitle; }
        set
        {
            _recordTitle = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("RecordTitle");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I think your usage of SelectedValue is wrong. try replacing it with SelectedValuePath

Comment: changed it and the error is the same. Do you need the models as well?

Comment: Describe furhter what you are trying to do because it is not clear. What do you want to be the Itemssource what to be displayed and what to be selectedvalue. I ask these because: CategoryList is an Observable collection of strings. Since you set ItemSource to this Observable collection DisplayMemberPath and SelectedValue (Path or not) are of no use.

Comment: ItemsSource is a list of strings I plan to get shown on the listView. I don't know if I need DisplayMemberPath to display such a list but I figured why not? SelectedValue binds the selected element of the ListView. Thats all.

Comment: Check my answer i think i ve got it (i edited it since my first post so check again)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your `DisplayMemberPath` binding is causing the error, and in your case should be removed entirely since it is not needed.

To use `DisplayMemberPath`, you need to be able to reference the property like `ListView.ItemsSource[X].SomeProperty`, where `SomeProperty` would be your `DisplayMemberPath`

You are getting this error because your `ItemsSource` is a `List<String>`, and `String` does not contain a property called `CategoryModel`.

To explain the exact binding error you have:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'CategoryModel' 
>   property not found on 'object' ''String' (HashCode=-57655201)'.
>   BindingExpression:Path=CategoryModel.CategoryList; DataItem='String'
>   (HashCode=-57655201); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is
>   'Text' (type 'String')

- This line means it can't find the property `CategoryModel` on the object `String`

  > BindingExpression path error: 'CategoryModel' 
  >   property not found on 'object' ''String' (HashCode=-57655201)'
- This line contains the `Path` property for the binding expression that is throwing the error

  > BindingExpression:Path=CategoryModel.CategoryList;
- This line tells you the  Source object for the binding that is throwing the error (typically the `DataContext`)

  > DataItem='String'
  >   (HashCode=-57655201);
- And this line means it is failing to bind the property `Text` on a `TextBox` (`DisplayMemberPath` is a shortcut way of making the `ItemTemplate` a single `TextBlock`, with it's `Text` bound to the `DisplayMemberPath` property)

  > target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is
  >   'Text' (type 'String')

So to put it all together, it is telling you that it is trying to bind `TextBox.Text` to `{Binding Path=CategoryModel.CategoryList}`, however the `DataContext` behind the `TextBox` is of type `String`, and `String` does not have a property called `CategoryModel`

Comment: Yup, exactly the problem. Thanks for the detailed explanations.

Comment: +1, and btw when i got binding errors and i think the xaml bindings are ok - then the datacontext is most time the wrong one :) thats why i always check the datacontext first

Comment: One other gotcha, if the object is a `Task` there may be a missing `await`

Answer (score 0):

The below static binding also may help you.

```
<Window.Resources>
  <local:CategoryModel x:Key="objCategory" />
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
  <ListView x:Name="categoryListView" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
            Width="56" Height="156" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource objCategory}, Path=CategoryList}"        
            VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" />
</Grid>
```