# Set UserControl in teleik RadTabIten content

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik

Im use telerik RadTabControl and in the ItemContent I have binding to UserControl property.

My code:

```
<telerik:RadTabControl ItemsSource="{Biding UIPlugins}" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource HeaderTemplate}" ContentTemplate="{DynamicResource ContentTemplate}"/>
```

Templates:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="HeaderTemplate">
   <StackPanel>
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}"/>
   </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate x:Type="ContentTemplate">
   <Grid>
      <ContentControl Content="{Binding Control}"/>
   </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

When I run the application I see in the output window this error:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error:
>   'Presenters' property not found on 'object' ''UIPlugin'
>   (HashCode=28505784)'. BindingExpression: Path=Presenters;
>   DataItem='UIPlugin' (HashCode=28505784); target element is
>   'ItemsControl' (Name=' '); target property is 'ItemsSource' (type
>   'IEnumerable')

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14481538/bindingexpression-path-error

It's not help?

Answer (score 0):

Your example code has several spelling and other mistakes, I've correct those and created a solution using DataTemplates for the RadTabControl Item & Content templates.

This example is built based on you using the MVVM pattern.

The XAML, a simple window containing a RadTabControl:

```
<Window.Resources>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="TabHeaderTemplate"
                  DataType="{x:Type app:ItemViewModel}">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Header}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="TabContentTemplate">
        <Grid>
            <ContentControl Content="{Binding}" />
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type app:ItemViewModel}">
        <Border Width="100"
                Height="100"
                Background="Red">

            <TextBlock Foreground="White"
                       FontWeight="Bold"
                       Text="{Binding Path=Value}" />
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>

</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <telerik:RadTabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                           ItemTemplate="{StaticResource TabHeaderTemplate}"
                           ContentTemplate="{StaticResource TabContentTemplate}" />

</Grid>
```

Here are the ViewModel I've created for this:

```
public class ItemViewModel
{
    public ItemViewModel(string header, string value)
    {
        Header = header;
        Value = value;
    }

    public string Header { get; private set; }

    public string Value { get; private set; }
}

public class MainViewModel
{
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        Items = new[]
        {
            new ItemViewModel("Header 1", "One"),
            new ItemViewModel("Header 2", "Two"),
            new ItemViewModel("Header 3", "Three"),
        };
    }

    public IEnumerable<ItemViewModel> Items { get; private set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you write the mistakes please?

Comment: <DataTemplate x:Type="ContentTemplate"> should be <DataTemplate x:Key="ContentTemplate">

Comment: Your code like what i do. Im use ObservableCollection and I can see the content of the header property but the error is in the binding to the UserControl

Comment: I think you want to replace the <ContentControl Content="{Binding Control}"/> with the <NAME_USER_CONTROL />

Comment: Its always was "x:Key" my mistake when i type the code here. I dont know the name of the usercontrol because i load it from plugin