# C# Code Behind Binding Object Property

Tags: c#, wpf

I would like to display my objects property in a listbox in code behind. Below is sample code:

```
    public ICollectionView LinksView;
    public ICollectionView AppsView;

    public string sortDirection;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        user = new User();

        LinksView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(user.MyLinks);
        listView_links.ItemsSource = LinksView;

        AppsView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(user.MyApps);
        listBox_apps.ItemsSource = AppsView;
    }
```

This displays the following:

[image]

The objects listed in the box contain a property called "Name" as seen here:

[image]

When I set listBox_apps.DisplayMemberPath = "Name"; I receive

```
bindingexpression path error 'Name'property not found on 'object'
```

Finally, just so you can see the "User" class...

[image]

How can I get the Name property of "Applications" to display in my listbox properly? I have been fighting this for the last few days and am brand spanking new to binding data. Thank you

**EDIT: As JH stated below in the comments - I needed to apply {get; set;} and it worked... Thanks!**

Comment: It only works with properties, not field members. Copy/paste Name from User class to Application class. You're missing the "{ get; set; }" part.

Comment: I believe this will help you why it caused: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14481538/bindingexpression-path-error